# How to solve Cross Domain (CORS) warnings for external scripts

Tags: javascript, azure, cors

I'm not sure if there are any duplicate questions, all the ones I have seen are for CORS issues within the same origin.

I am using this tool [owasp zap](https://owasp.org/www-project-zap/) to analayze security issues with my website.

Now I am noticing I am getting quite a few errors like so

[image]

`Cross-Domain Misconfiguration`

Now they all seem to come from external sources like google analytics etc...

How can I solve these issues? Is it an issue with my server? Issue with the front-end? or an issue with connecting to external scripts?

Can I safely ignore these errors, or do I need to fix them?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I solve these issues?

You can't.

> Is it an issue with my server?

No. The URL starts with www.google-analytics.com. That isn't your server.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to make sure this was the case